# Unable to save the docker image from jenkins

Tags: docker, shell, jenkins, automation

I am using Jenkins freestyle build job and my shell basically doing a simple job of pulling script from bitbucket and make the docker image but at the end, while I wanted to save the docker image in a .tar file .........that part is not working .....

am using following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/component/image
c=`ls -lrt | tail -n1 |  awk -F'.' '{print $4}' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'`

TAG=`expr $c + 1` 

cd ..



sed -i.bak s#__release__#$TAG# component.yaml

printf "Current tag - $TAG \n"
echo "Switching directory to COMPONENT"
pwd
ls -l
git branch -l
if [ -f $WORKSPACE/../CLEAN_BUILD_BFF ]; then
        echo "Doing a clean build"
        docker build --no-cache -t product:component.6.0.hotfix$TAG .


else
        echo "Doing a normal build"
        docker build -tproduct:component.6.0.hotfix$TAG .


fi

cd images

sudo -S docker save -o /home/ubuntu/test/scripts/images/dockerimage-name.tar dockerimage-name
```

but the last part where I want to save the docker image is not working, the script is unable to save the image in a .tar format

getting the following error :

/tmp/jenkins5681348791736054100.sh: line 31: cd: images: No such file or directory
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Seems a typo. At the top, you are doing `cd` to `image` dir. Later, at the end, you're trying to `cd` to `images`

Answer (score 1):

On the top, you are doing , where it's mentioned as `image` in the end

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/component/image
```

and in the end, you are doing , where it's `images`.

```
cd images
```

Could be a typo mistake. If not, then please try the below way to save the image in tar format. And there are couple of other typos as well in the script.

```
if [ -f $WORKSPACE/../CLEAN_BUILD_BFF ]; then
        echo "Doing a clean build"
        docker build --no-cache -t product:component.6.0.hotfix$TAG .
        docker save product:component.6.0.hotfix$TAG > product:component.6.0.hotfix$TAG.tar

else
        echo "Doing a normal build"
        docker build -t product:component.6.0.hotfix$TAG .  #Typo changed
        docker save product:component.6.0.hotfix$TAG > product:component.6.0.hotfix$TAG.tar


fi
```